# pip and setup.py install don't install actual modules, only egg-info

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, packaging, twine

I've made two packages (`pphp` and `xmlx`) and distributed and uploaded them the standard way, using `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` and `twine upload dist/*`.

I then tried installing them using `pip install`, and it *seemed* to work fine... but then, in the interactive shell:

```
>>> import xmlx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File <module>, line 1:
    import xmlx
ImportError: No module named xmlx
```

I then tried `python setup.py install` but same result (seemed fine but didn't work).

So what's going on?

Comment: There might be something wrong in your setup.py.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/Kenny2github/xmlx) is the repository for `xmlx`, yes?  [Your `setup.py`](https://github.com/Kenny2github/xmlx/blob/master/setup.py) declares the packages in your project with `packages=find_packages()`, but your project does not contain any [import packages](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-import-package), only a single-file module, `xmlx.py`.  This must be declared in your `setup.py` by instead writing:

```
py_modules=['xmlx']
```

(Also, `dist/` and `*.egg-info/` are build artifacts and should not be stored in version control; I recommend adding them to your `.gitignore`.)